# Virtual printer starting another application

Tags: printing

Is there any way to develop a virtual printer . my requirements are

I want my virtual printer come in printer select drop-down  (eg: as CutePDF printer writer )

When we select our custom virtual printer, open another application and transfer printer data to that application

Please help me to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

For the "driver" I guess you can use existing ones, e.g. Microsoft Postscript driver. What you need is a Print Monitor written in C which will receive the output of the "driver" (If you use Microsoft Postscript driver, the file will be a Postscript file) and then invoke the program you want. For details, please install Windows DDK and look at src\print\monitors\